# Internal Server Error with Postgres and Python

Tags: python, postgresql, internal-server-error

I keep getting this error: "**Internal Server Error** The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

This error only happens when I try to add new data to the database's tables through a website. The website is being run on a losthost. I'm not sure if postgres is the problem or if the open source python code I'm using with postgres is the issue. Postgres is running on port 5432, but I'm not sure what data cluster it's using. Since when I try `pg_ctl -D data status` (data being the data cluster folder) it says `pg_ctl: no server running`. But that could just be because I'm putting in the wrong data cluster folder. If I try `sudo lsof -i :5432` to see if anything is running on port 5432 it gives

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres  83 postgres    4u  IPv6 0x261d777f749af8e3      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  83 postgres    5u  IPv4 0x261d777f769f7233      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

I believe postgres and the python code are talking to each other since when I initiated the website with the python code it made 30 new tables in postgres to go with it. I just am at a lost for what is wrong. The error is not descriptive at all.

**Edit:**
If I query `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';` it give this file path: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data. Then using `pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data status` it still says `pg_ctl: no server running`. So why does it say postgres is running on the port if the other command says there is no server running?

Comment: You need to break the problem apart into pieces. 1) Can you connect via psql. 2) Can you perform said operations in PSQL? 3) Can you perform simple queries in python, so on and so forth. Also check the logs, they may contain better errors or some information about what led to the internal server error. "Internal server error" is typically an error indicating that something went wrong trying to parse a CGI (i.e. your web page).

Comment: I can do anything in postgres in the terminal or pgadim, that all works. I can run code in python, but I'm not sure about queries since I've never used python to do them. (The open source code just so happened to be written in python). Where are the log files located? Are you talking about the Postgres log files or does python happen to have any?